# Indoor mint leaves rapidly turning brown!

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, mint

[image]

My poor mint plant is losing leaves at an alarming pace. I’m not the best gardener, but how do I save this little guy? No idea what’s causing the fast browning!

I’ve been trying to water it every other day and it’s on a window sill. I have grow lights I could turn on, if that would help?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Can't see the pot in the picture, so a few questions for clarification... how long have you had the plant? What size is the pot its in, and does it have drainage holes? I take it you're growing this indoors?